# How to avoid the use of (php?id=idNumber) using php

Tags: php

I need to know a better way of retrieving data from the db. In the page I am developing when I click on check product button for example, the id of that specific product is passed to the product page  such as http://domainname.com/products.php?id=1.
Apparently this is a bad way to retrieve data. How can I pass this id value to the products page without using ?id=1.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using `$_GET` how about `$_POST`?

Comment: `Apparently this is a bad way to retrieve data` Who told you such nonsense ?

Comment: you can encode url parameters with cryptography algorithms

Answer (score 3):

> Apparently this is a bad way to retrieve data

It is totally untrue. Using $_POST instead of $_GET in this case make the page for specific product inaccessible by pure URL. What if I want to share a link of product with id 2321 to my friend in facebook?

> Take a look as this website for example londonperfumeshop.co.uk/diesel-zero-plus-men. The product I guess is retrieved from the database but there is no id passed through the domain. How is that done in php? – user2257461

This is called **URL Rewrite**. Basically, it is not PHP feature. It is a web server feature. The concept behind URL rewrite is to map a pattern of URL into another pattern of URL. For example. I want to map

- `products/(.*) -> products.php?alias=$1`

If someone try to access the following link:

- products/url-rewrite-for-dummy
- products/head-first-web-mobile

It will map to the following link:

- products.php?alias=url-rewrite-for-dummy
- products.php?alias=head-first-web-mobile

So basically, it's still a $_GET. While using alias make your URL looks prettier and friendlier, there is a small problem. Alias can be changed. Lets say you want to rename your product, so the alias should be also changed. It causes the old link to be invalid. To overcome this problem, you can combine alias with id.

- `products/([0-9]+)-(.*) -> products.php?id=$1`

If someone try to access the following link:

- products/1-url-rewrite-for-dummy
- products/2-head-first-web-mobile

It will map to the following link:

- products.php?id=1
- products.php?id=2

Using ID with alias improve the speed of query; and ID of a product will always still the same (it would be unusual for product ID to be changed)

Comment: It makes the URL a bit ugly, but it's no worse than using PATH_INFO and a URL like `/products.php/1`.  You'd need to do some URL rewriting to get a pretty URL, and it's often not worth it.

Comment: Take a look as this website for example http://www.londonperfumeshop.co.uk/diesel-zero-plus-men. The product I guess is retrieved from the database but there is no id passed through the domain. How is that done in php?

Comment: For Apache, use .htaccess. For IIS, use URL rewrite. Instead of using ID, it use alias.

Comment: @user2257461 the URL is rewritten, search for `pretty urls`. What's funny is that they are using `$_GET` :p

Comment: Updated explanation about URL rewrite.